# Could not import ''. The path must be fully qualified

Tags: python, django, import

I am working with Django for a few months and built this website just for fun and further improving myself and I can't for the life of me get rid of this error, I have looked for all my code and can't find this import error and for some reason it won't tell where it's going wrong. This is the error. However, the weird thing is that is doesn't always happen on this page, its like they are taking turns in erroring out, for example, I am able to log in without any issues sometimes but on occasion, I get this error and all I have to do is just reload the page and enter my details again.

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://www.enfieldgrammar.tk/account/login/?next=/account/

Django Version: 1.11b1
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['accounts',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  178.             response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py" in process_view
  314.                 return self._reject(request, REASON_BAD_TOKEN)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py" in _reject
  163.         return _get_failure_view()(request, reason=reason)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py" in _get_failure_view
  43.     return get_callable(settings.CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/utils.py" in get_callable
  27.         raise ImportError("Could not import '%s'. The path must be fully qualified." % lookup_view)

Exception Type: ImportError at /account/login/
Exception Value: Could not import ''. The path must be fully qualified.
```

Comment: Have you overriden `settings.CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW`. What's the output when you run `python manage.py shell`, and print `settings.CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of your stack trace, here's whats happening:

- You are sending Django a HTTP POST request
- You have the [CSRF Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/) installed; which is a good thing. Read more about CSRF here.
- The POST request does not have the CSRF Token, which raises an error in Django.
- Django is trying to show you the default view that gets shown for CSRF failures. This is controlled by `settings.CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW` -> which defaults to `django.views.csrf.csrf_failure` as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#csrf-failure-view).
- Django however seems to be looking for a view which is the empty string `''`

Based on this, it looks like your project's settings is setting the value for `settings.CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW` to the empty string `''` -> how and where this is happening is what you need to debug further.

My guess is are using some kind of wrapper to get `setting` variables from environment, with a fallback to the empty string `''`, which is overriding Django's default fallback to `django.views.csrf.csrf_failure`

Comment: I am such an idiot I had left this in my settings file 

CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW = ''